# Debug micronaut application in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, micronaut

I have created a `java` `micronaut` application in `Eclipse IDE`. The microservice is able to build and run successfully via `commandline` but I'd like to know if there is a way to add breakpoints in the application for `debugging` just the way we debug any normal `java` application?
I did try the solution mentioned here [Debug java micronaut microservice in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509794/debug-java-micronaut-microservice-in-visual-studio-code).

I added `run.jvmArgs('-Dmicronaut.environments=dev','-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1', '-Xdebug',"-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n", '-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')` configuration
 to `build.gradle`.

When I build and run the project again, I see

```
> Task :run
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000 
12:53:51.084 [main] INFO i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [dev]
12:53:53.809 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 3102ms. Server Running: http://localhost:6030
```

So how do I add breakpoints and debug the microservice now?

Answer (score 0):

In this setup, the JVM is listening on a socket for a debugger to attach. In Eclipse, you can create a remote debug configuration for this:

- Run -> Debug Configurations
- Make new Launch configuration under Remote Java Application
- Ensure the right project is selected. Under Connection Properties, let it connect to `localhost` on port `8000` (which happens to be the default)
- Click Debug